# Как разбить результат запроса к базе данных mysql на две части, а потом их "склеить"

Tags: mysql, webix

Есть запрос с базе данных mysql. он возвращает 83000 строк. при отправке результата на сайт выпадает ошибка о превышении лимита 256М. Подскажите как мне разбить этот результат на 2 части, отправить, и "склеить". на сайте данные выводятся так -  webix.$$("artsku").load(GET-запрос)

Comment: *как мне разбить этот результат на 2 части* Использовать LIMIT. И, если строго 2 части, при разной сортировке (а то "хвост" будет выбираться очень небыстро).

Comment: Хотя мне жаль того клиента, который будет смотреть (и даже просто получать с сервера) все 83000 записей...

Comment: в webix создаешь datatable с pagging и

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить limit, например, 50 или 100 - выдать их, а в JS код передать последний id. Далее догружать всё остальное через Ajax, передавая этот последний id, получая в ответе очередную порцию и новый id для следующего Ajax запроса.

В скрипте будет в SQL что-то, типа where id > X limit 50...

Разумеется, учтите передачу флага, что данные закончились и теребить сервер запросами дальше не стоит ;)